# How to save dismissable notice state in WP 4.2?

Tags: admin, ajax, admin-ui

In [WordPress 4.2](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/23/spinners-and-dismissible-admin-notices-in-4-2/) the `is-dismissible` class was introduced to allow notices to be dismissed.

This code is working to add the notice.

```
function prefix_deprecated_hook_admin_notice() {
    if ( has_filter( 'prefix_filter' ) ) { ?>
        <div class="updated notice is-dismissible">
            <p><?php _e( 'Notice', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php }
}
add_action( 'admin_notices', 'prefix_deprecated_hook_admin_notice' );
```

I am able to dismiss the notice but I am unsure how I can save the state when the notice is dismissed with AJAX.

Comment: Could you show us the code you're using for hiding this notice?

Comment: The CSS can be found here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/css/common.css#L1296 The JS can be seen here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/js/common.js#L379

Answer (score 5):

There's no need for a library, it's fairly straightforward to accomplish.  If you are coding your own plugin (which it appears you are), then you can do this in a fairly lightweight way:

A slightly modified version of the notice, which checks if it's been dismissed before displaying, and stores the "type" of notice in the markup for access in javascript:

```
function prefix_deprecated_hook_admin_notice() {
    if ( has_filter( 'prefix_filter' ) ) { 
        // Check if it's been dismissed...
        if ( ! get_option('dismissed-prefix_deprecated', FALSE ) ) { 
            // Added the class "notice-my-class" so jQuery pick it up and pass via AJAX,
            // and added "data-notice" attribute in order to track multiple / different notices
            // multiple dismissible notice states ?>
            <div class="updated notice notice-my-class is-dismissible" data-notice="prefix_deprecated">
                <p><?php _e( 'Notice', 'my-text-domain' ); ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php }
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_notices', 'prefix_deprecated_hook_admin_notice' );
```

And then, the following jQuery

```
  // shorthand no-conflict safe document-ready function
  jQuery(function($) {
    // Hook into the "notice-my-class" class we added to the notice, so
    // Only listen to YOUR notices being dismissed
    $( document ).on( 'click', '.notice-my-class .notice-dismiss', function () {
        // Read the "data-notice" information to track which notice
        // is being dismissed and send it via AJAX
        var type = $( this ).closest( '.notice-my-class' ).data( 'notice' );
        // Make an AJAX call
        // Since WP 2.8 ajaxurl is always defined in the admin header and points to admin-ajax.php
        $.ajax( ajaxurl,
          {
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
              action: 'dismissed_notice_handler',
              type: type,
            }
          } );
      } );
  });
```

In PHP, set up the AJAX hooks to capture the AJAX call:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_dismissed_notice_handler', 'ajax_notice_handler' );

/**
 * AJAX handler to store the state of dismissible notices.
 */
function ajax_notice_handler() {
    // Pick up the notice "type" - passed via jQuery (the "data-notice" attribute on the notice)
    $type = self::request( 'type' );
    // Store it in the options table
    update_option( 'dismissed-' . $type, TRUE );
}
```

And that's it!  No library needed - especially if you've already got PHP and javascript files loading.

This method is per the [WordPress Core dev team blog](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/04/23/spinners-and-dismissible-admin-notices-in-4-2/)

Comment: Thanks for the write up, very helpful. For those that have issues with `$type = self::request('type');` you can also access the value via `POST` super global as `$type = $_POST['type']`. Im unsure about `self` here, as it looks as the OP is using procedural functions and not methods. At any rate I received `Fatal warning: Cannot use "self" when no class scope is active ...`.

Comment: Also it's worth mentioning, if you're using this as a quick primer for wp ajax transactions in general, this example doesn't include the use of a `nonce` or sanitise the incoming `$type` data. In this case it's okay, but if  applied to more complex ajax transactions, you'd want to use both for security reasons.

Comment: After a quick look at the documentation for `WP_Http::request()` method, I'm not seeing any in-built sanitisation, so a quick application of 'sanitize_html_class($type)` might not be such a bad idea for either the `request` method or `POST`. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_html_class

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was a small library. https://github.com/CalderaWP/dismissible_notice

It is backward compatible till WordPress 3.8.

Comment: Also an alternative library is [here](https://github.com/collizo4sky/persist-admin-notices-dismissal), small and solid.

Answer (score 0):

I doing that, no library needed:

```
function general_admin_notice()
{
    global $pagenow;
    
    if ( $pagenow == 'admin.php' )
    {
        $todaykey="somekey".date("Ymd");
        
        if ( $_COOKIE[$todaykey]??0 ) 
            return;
        
        print "<div class='notice notice-warning is-dismissible' onmousedown='document.cookie=\"$todaykey=1\";'>";
        print '<p>Something to tell</p>';
        print '</div>';
    }
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'general_admin_notice');
```

I just check for a `mousedown` inside for more simplicity but you can check for a `mousedown` in the dismiss button too, with a bit more javascript...